# How to integrate ADF application to E-business suite

Tags: oracle-adf

I have developed one application in Oracle Adf then i want to integrate this application to e-business suite.so please let me know any one knows the process ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a HUGE question and you would be better off googling [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/ebs-sdk-adf-1887167.pdf).

When I have done integrations before we usually access custom tables produced FROM EBS within the ADF apps. We also usually send security and role info from EBS to ADF via the URL and called the ADF app as a menu/url in EBS.